# Como ordenar um ARRAY de Objetos baseado na ordem de outro ARRAY de Objetos

Tags: javascript, html, css, array, objetos

Como ordernar um array de objetos com base na ordem de outro array de objetos porém alterando os campos atualizados do primeiro array de objetos?

```js
const arrayEntrada = [
  {
    name: 'asd',
    id: 1,
    status: 1,
  },
  {
    name: 'dsa',
    id: 2,
    status: 1,
  },
];

const arrayBaseOrdem = [
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'dsa',
    status: 0,
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'asd',
    statusbar: 0,
  },
];

const arraySaidaEsperada = [
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'dsa',
    status: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'asd',
    statusbar: 1,
  },
];
```

Como organizar o ***arrayEntrada*** com base no ***arrayBaseOrdem*** mas alterando os campos atualizados do ***arrayEntrada***

Comment: Caso a resposta tenha resolvido sua dúvida, peço por favor que considere marcar a resposta como aceita clicando no ícone ✔ ao lado da mesma.

Answer (score 0):

Partindo do princípio que o valor da propriedade `name` é único, poderia ser usado o método [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) para alcançar o resultado desejado desta forma:

```
const arraySaidaEsperada = arrayBaseOrdem.map(object => arrayEntrada.find(i => i.name === object.name));
```

No caso é criado um novo `Array` iterando sobre os objetos de `arrayBaseOrdem` e buscando pelos equivalentes de `arrayEntrada` baseado na propriedade `name`.

A única limitação disso é, conforme mencionado anteriormente, se existir mais de um objeto com o mesmo valor nessa propriedade só iria ser usado o primeiro usando o método [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).